# How to debug a Golang program in VS Code using delve?

Tags: visual-studio-code, delve

I am trying to debug my code using delve. My code builds. But when I start a debug session, delve cannot build it.

I am using VS Code. I click on the run and debug button on the left. Then the button to the left of launch pad on the lop. I get compiler errors:

`./myprogram.go:118:32`: too many errors (exit status 1).

This is my `launch.json` file:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "myprogram.go"
    }
]
```

Do you know what the problem is?

I read the delve tutorials, but I could not find anything which addresses the issue.

I chose Delve because it was written by the Golang team.

Any suggestions for another debugger?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that my code builds. It runs but does not produce the correct results.

Comment: Yes I am sure that the files are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code builds?
Maybe the file that is built is different from the one in the launch.json file ie. "myprogram.go".
Can you confirm that this is the file?

Comment: Yes I am sure that the files are the same.

Comment: Can you try to test debugging another sample code like some hello world template, and see if you can debug it?

Comment: I tested delve with hello world and it worked.

Comment: Could the problem with my program be related to the fact that it is a web server application?

Comment: Are you able to run the executable built from the terminal? If you are able to can you post the output/ errors?